# Functions in custom theme

Tags: functions, themes

We are a group of 4 who is making a website for a school project. One of the criterias was that we had to script our own theme from scratch. Since we had no experience or knowledge of scripting we followed tutorials we found. The theme kind of works but we are missing most of the basic wordpress functions. We have tried to add the functions.php to our theme, because we did not have it, but we either didn't get any changes or the website crashed.

We can't find a way to make this work and we would love to get some help.

Link to all our scripts: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a9f44a2218f1e40ec2d760d15b608f0

Comment: You want to know how to add `functions.php` in theme?

Comment: We want to know how to add all the basic wordpress functions to our theme without the site crashing.

Comment: What do you mean that you tried yo add the`function.php` to your theme? You create a new file called `function.php` in your theme folder or you copied the `wp-includes/function.php` in your theme?

Comment: We tried both @Laxmana. Nothing worked.

Comment: If you have a wordpress installation all the basic wordpress function are available to use them. Just create an empty `function.php` file inside your theme folder. Inside this file you can call all wordpress function based on your needs

Comment: The second one (copy) is wrong and you should never do it. The first case is the correct one. Please tell us what exactly are you doing.

Comment: We did make an empty functions.php within our theme but we don't really know what to do becasue we don't have much experience with wordpress.

Comment: Ok, what you want to do ? What is the goal?

Comment: Our goal is to get a website with all the functions that standard wordpress themes have. We would also like to have a clickable logo and make the top navigation bar stick and follow when we scroll down on the page.

Comment: But you already have it :) You can read the code of `Twenty Seventeen` theme to get ideas. I think you misunderstand the concept of `function.php`. The purpose of this file is to write your own code (functios, add hooks & filters etc). The WordPress functions are already available. WordPress  read the file and "execute" the code inside that file. It's up to you what that file will contain depending what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using functions.php**
Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child theme does not override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded right before the parent’s file.)

In that way, the functions.php of a child theme provides a smart, trouble-free method of modifying the functionality of a parent theme. Say that you want to add a PHP function to your theme. The fastest way would be to open its functions.php file and put the function there. But that’s not smart: The next time your theme is updated, your function will disappear. But there is an alternative way which is the smart way: you can create a child theme, add a functions.php file in it, and add your function to that file. The function will do the exact same job from there too, with the advantage that it will not be affected by future updates of the parent theme. Do not copy the full content of functions.php of the parent theme into functions.php in the child theme.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes